# MSVC13 looking for wrong library version of boost

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, linker

I'm using boost 1.57 and everything is fine and dandy until the linker starts doing its magic. For some reason it's looking for libboost-*-1_56.lib instead of 1_57. Does anyone have any idea how this happens and what to do about it? I'm using msvc13.

I'm sorry if this is a very novice novice question but I've been searching for hours.

Comment: Use showIncludes option in VC++ to pinpoint which file is including boost headers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Usually happens because... you're including the headers from boost 1.56

Boost has automatic linking on MSVC: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking

Comment: Problem is I'm not including anything, boost is a dependency. I'm trying to run an example code so I know that it should be possible as is (did a all-in-one install).

Comment: How can it be a dependency if you're not using it?

Comment: I must sound really stupid now.

I'm trying to make PCL work. Doing that I'm running an example. I include some of that, and it again includes boost. What i find weird is that this has obviously worked for others, but somehow manage not to for me

Comment: @Phenalor looks like PCL is finding the Boost 1.56 headers (perhaps they're bundled, even)

Comment: Yeah, i just cant understand how or why, I've never had boost 1.56 installed, I'm not including any other directories, I've checked my environment path. I simply have no idea where its getting 1.56 from